# WSO2 SSLHandshakeException on Login

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am encountering this error when logging into the API Publisher and API Store Listing sites.

I am using the admin/admin user

```
Unable to log you in!
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: How did you login? Through browser or a client application?

Comment: are you using a your own certificate or wso2 provided default  certificate

Comment: Are you using any Load balancer in front of the product?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your SSL certificate which you are using is not a CA signed certificate. Please update your SSL certificate to CA signed certificate and this problem will go away.